# date.format in Chrome 5

Tags: javascript, date, google-chrome

I'm experiencing something really strange with my javascript in chrome with Date().format.

If I use the console and type:

```
d = new Date(Date.parse("2010-05-28"))
d.format("yyyy-MM-dd");
""
d._toFormattedString();
"Fri May 28 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)"
```

Anyone got any clue why I get an empty string? And it's only in Chrome, didn't happen in Chrome 4, and it doesn't happen in IE8/Firefox3.5

Comment: There is no method called `format` on the standard JavaScript `Date` object. Did you mean something else?

Comment: hmm, I honestly had no clue, why does it work sometimes then? What I want is the date in the format: 2010-05-28

Comment: Look at my second edit to see how to obtain what you want.

Comment: It's the ASP.NET AJAX library.

Comment: oh, thank you bobince.

So any clue on why this behavior in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `format` function in the [`Date` object.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Are you getting that function from a plugin?
If so then I suggest you read the APIs looking for the possible parameters.

I don't know if this might help, but all the plugins I tried required two "y" to get the four digit year string.

```
d = new Date(Date.parse("2010-05-28"))
d.format("yy-MM-dd");
```

EDIT: Some other plugin uses the uppercase "Y", like `d.format("Y-m-d");`

**EDIT2**: It seems like you need to just format your date to "yyyy-MM-dd".
You can add this prototype function in your code:

```
Date.prototype.toMyPreferredFormat = function(){
  var dd=this.getDate();
  if(dd<10)dd='0'+dd;
  var mm=this.getMonth()+1;
  if(mm<10)mm='0'+mm;
  var yyyy=this.getFullYear();
  return String(yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd);
}
```

And use it like:

```
d = new Date(Date.parse("2010-05-28"))
d.toMyPreferredFormat();
```

[Source](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-67608.html) of the prototype function

Comment: The only plugin I use is jQuery. And I swear that d.format("yyyy-MM-dd") did work in previously build